# Unable to intercept PowerShell remote traffic using Titanium Web Proxy

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-remoting, titanium-web-proxy

I want to intercept PowerShell remote traffic. I want to use Titanium because I need to do some intermediate processing on the requests. When I launch the **Titanium.Web.Proxy.Examples.Wpf** app, out-of-the-box it intercepts all the browser traffic, but not PowerShell remote (`Enter-PSSession -ConnectionUri http://localhost:5985/WSMAN/`... etc.).  I have found that I can see this traffic using Fiddler (requires a bit of tweaking), so I know the traffic can be intercepted. What needs to be done for or in Titanium that isn't happening "out-of-the-box"?

**EDIT:**

Additional notes:

- I had seen Fiddler capture the WSMAN traffic on one occasion, but have been unable to reproduce it for reasons as yet unknown.
- The final implementation will be in a C# assembly, using `RunspaceFactory` and `WSManConnectionInfo`, not PowerShell scripting; the `Enter-PSSession` command above was for illustrative purposes only.
- When uri is specified as http://127.0.0.1:5985/WSMAN and `ProxyAccessType` of anything other than `None` is specified for `WSManConnectionInfo`, the following exception is thrown: System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: 'Connecting to remote server 127.0.0.1 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Setting proxy information is not valid when the HTTP transport is specified.

Comment: After the application has started, try `$session = New-PSSession ... -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -ProxyAccessType AutoDetect)` (try `IEConfig` as the `-ProxyAccessType` option if auto detect doesn't work)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  Actual usage is from C# where we do: `new WSManConnectionInfo(psUriBuilder.Uri, ExchangeShellSchema, credentials) { AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic}`; if I add `ProxyAccessType = ProxyAccessType.AutoDetect` (or anything other than `None`), I get System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: 'Connecting to remote server 127.0.0.1 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Setting proxy information is not valid when the HTTP transport is specified.  (for Uri ttp://127.0.0.1:5985/WSMAN)